# How to consecutively show detailed text of tableViewCell in the SecondVC

Tags: swift

I have two VCs. The first contains three elements and three header. I want to show detailed version of each line in the SecondVC. I have written the code below but all three rows in SecondVc (both header and text) shows first line of text in FirstVc.How can i make in the SecondVc that each rows exactly describe the same as in first VC. Below is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return items[row]?.title
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]?.content 
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black
    cell.textLabel?.alpha = 0.5 
    return cell
}
```

Thank you in advance

Here is how i'am trying to pass the data between controllers:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    let category = result?.data[indexPath.section]
    
    let vc = ListViewController(items: result!.data) 
    vc.title = category?.title
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your reply.I am using pushViewcontroller method.

Comment: @Rob Now i am going to add that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `didSelectRowAt`, you are setting the title on the basis of the `category`, but you are passing the entire `result!.data` without telling it which row was selected. Sure, the title is presumably correct, but it has no way of knowing which row’s details it should show.

You could solve this by adding a parameter which indicates which row was selected. But I would suggest refactoring this, not passing the whole array `result!.data`, but rather just the selected row (e.g. the contents of your `category` variable). So, change the `init` method of the second view controller to not expect an entire array, but a single row, and then supply `category`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But Content of Category is the codable struct.Its hard to implement this way.

Comment: struct ResultItem: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let content: String
}

Comment: First, there’s no reason you couldn’t just have a `let item: ResultItem` rather than `let items: [ResultItem]`. The fact that it is a `struct`, much less `Codable`, is irrelevant. Second, while I think it is preferable to refactor the details VC to have a model of a single `ResultItem` (it is, as I understand, designed to show details for one item, so to require it to receive the full array is, with no offense, strange). But, as I pointed out, you could leave it as is and alternatively just supply the destination a second parameter for the selected item index and be done with it.

Comment: You are right,i should create array of content form ResultItem struct,Do you know how can i create array of codable struct property?

Comment: It feels like we’re drifting away from he question at hand. These unrelated questions, in the comments above, should be deleted and if you have another question, then research that on S.O. and post another question if needed.

Comment: That having been said, you create array of codable struct properties precisely the way you create an array of struct properties (i.e. the fact that it’s codable is immaterial). E.g. `var items: [ResultItem] = []` or `var items: [ResultItem] = [ResultItem(…), ResultItem(…)]`.

Comment: I didnt understand why?